# header_slider is empty, where can I fill it?

Tags: template, slider

I am fairly new to Magento.

I am trying to get a slider and I think I found the default in de thema I'm using. It looks like this in de header.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header_slider') ?>
```

When I var_dump this it's empty. Where can I fill this?

The theme I'm using is this: http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/51048.html and the header I want is this:

[image]

Comment: There are 2 possible places where the theme could have added this data. have you check your static blocks for a block with code header_slider, if its not found there open up your local.xml and search for template that renders the header_slider

Comment: There isn't a use of header_template in static blocks (In the CMS  on the admin panel right?) I;m not quite sure what I am looking for in the local.xml though.

Comment: in app/design/frontend/{{your_package_name}}/{{your_theme}}/layout/local.xml   look for a  <block> tag whose name attribute or alias attribute is header_slider. alternatively you could paste the local.xml in paste bin ald let me have a look at it for you.

Comment: Is it possible this file doesn't exist? I can't seem to find it...

Comment: it is possible. Does your theme include any module for banners? if so then most probably the code your are looking for resides in that layout xml file

Comment: I very much doubt it does include that now. I am going to contact the theme maker. Thanks for your help thus far, it's been helpful!